# how to add an item to a object initialized with { blah = "asdf" }

Tags: c#, object-initializer

how to add an item to an object initialized with:

```
object obj = new { blah = "asdf" };
```

If I want to add another key value pair, how would i?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't modify the object's anonymous type definition once you make the object using that initializer syntax. That is, once you initialize it with `{ blah = "asdf" }`, it only has that `blah` property. You can't add another. This is because anonymous types are static types.

The [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) answers work though, for a `dynamic` object. See the other answers for that.

If you're really just trying to manage a collection of key-value pairs (kinda sorta based on the way you phrased your question), use a dictionary.

```
var kvp = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "blah", "asdf" }
};

kvp.Add("womp", "zxcv");
```

Answer (score 7):

@BoltClock is right on. Another alternative is to use an ExpandoObject, at the loss of intellisense.

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.blah = "asdf";

// sometime later

obj.somethingelse = "dfgh";

// obj now has 'blah' and 'somethingelse' 'properties'
```

Answer (score 6):

Once you define an object like that, you're done. You can't add anything to it.

If you're using C# 4.0, though, you could always use a dynamic type:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

obj.blah = "asdf";
obj.blahBlah = "jkl;";
```

Comment: It's .NET 4 like you said and not just C# 4, right? I read about something called the DLR...

Comment: @BoltClock The DLR runs as a component of .NET 4.

Comment: @BoltClock - The dynamic keyword is a C# feature but it does make use of the DLR (which also powers other dynamic languages).